# Python Error in Spyder: No Module found" error

Tags: python, installation, package, spyder

I have installed the `pygsp` package in `anaconda` using `conda` command and I can import it and use it in my `Anaconda Prompt` (base environment) but when I launch the `spyder` I get `No Module found" error`.

Note: running `print(sys.executable)` for the `anaconda prompt` is `python.exe` while for `spyder` it's `pysthonw.exe` (both in the same path).

Any comment/answer is appreciated.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [this guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to understand how to fix this problem.